# Confirm extender to anchor tag

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I am using a CSS button as

```
<a href="" class="btn green" title="Delete" OnServerClick="MyCodeBehindFunction">Delete </a>
```

Previously, I was using a button control instead of CSS button and using AJAX confirm extender before deleting. But how do I ask for this confirm action in `< a href="">` now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's done the same way as with the `Button` control. Use `LinkButton` control instead of plain `<a />` tag:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="myLink" CssClass="btn green" ToolTip="Delete" Text="Delete"
    OnClick="MyCodeBehindFunction" runat="server" />

<ajax:ConfirmButtonExtender TargetControlID="myLink" ... runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

`<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkbtn" Text="Delete"
    OnClick="MyCodeBehindFunction" runat="server" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure to Delete?');"/>`